# iOS 7 TableviewCell colored line

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

How are you all. I'm having a weird issue with my tableviewcell. When I runn this on Simulator. It shows proper layout as in image 1.

[image: Image on simulator]

but when I run this on device. It has colored lines in it on all tableviews of app, like image 2. [image]

Is this something with iOS 7? I've cleared background color of cell in tablview:willDisplayCell:.

Code is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 BarsCustomCell *cell= [BarsCustomCell resuableCellForTableView:tableView withOwner:self];

  Bars *currentValue= [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        if(indexPath.row==(self.data.count-1)){
            [cell updateWithBars:currentValue isLast:YES isFirst:NO] ;
        }else if (indexPath.row==0){

            [cell updateWithBars:currentValue isLast:NO isFirst:YES] ;
        }else{

            [cell updateWithBars:currentValue isLast:NO isFirst:NO] ;
        }
}
```

and Tableviewcell sublcassm method for updating.

```
-(void) updateWithBars:(Bars *)bars isLast:(BOOL)isLast isFirst:(BOOL)isFirst{

    self.nameLbl.text= bars.name;
    self.addressLbl.text= bars.vicinity;

    double distance = [[[LOTVLocationManager sharedManager] mockedLocation] distanceFromLocation:bars.location];
    self.distanceLbl.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km",distance/1000];


    if(isFirst){
        self.bgImageview.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"sport_top_bg.png"];
        self.nameLbl.center= CGPointMake(self.nameLbl.center.x, self.nameLbl.center.y+3);
    }
    else if(isLast){
        self.bgImageview.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"sport_bottom_bg.png"];
        self.addressLbl.center= CGPointMake(self.addressLbl.center.x, self.addressLbl.center.y-3);
    }

}
```

Comment: you say: "When I runn this on device. It shows proper layout as in image 1." and: "but when I run this on device. It has colored lines in it on all tableviews of app, like image 2." what is the difference? you're always run on the device? or maybe you meant simulator ..

Comment: oops sorry. I've edited it. It was simulator in 1st one. Thanks for the point.

Comment: Can you post some code in "- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" or your subclass of UITableViewCell if you have.

Comment: Check the images you're using. Is the non-retina ok and the retina image wrong (or vice-versa). Also, `nil` the image if it isn't first or last (remember the cells are being reused).

Comment: Could you add the code in the BarsCustomCell class as well?

Comment: it has only methid there. i've added this already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. It was due to TableviewCell's background color. Some iOS Versions support cell.backgroundColor and some support only cell.contentView.backgroundColor. I wrote both for cell and contentView to fix the issue.